How to check if Message was acknowledged Spring Kafka
In Spring Kafka i try to write a Integration test that sends a message to my embedded Kafka Topic
now i want to use Awailitly to check if a Message was acknowledged and then check if something was written to the Database or not.
SomeMessage someMessage = getDefaultMessage().withSomeOtherAppId("ABC");


/* act */
kafkaTemplate.send(replayTopic, mdoUpdateEvent);

/* assert */
Awaitility.await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).until(() ->

// I tried spy on the filter and count invocations in the unitl()
// I tried setting up another messageListener on the container and count received messages in the unitl()
  );
assertThat(repo.count()).isEqualTo(0);

Both of my attempts didnt work so far is there another way of ensuring a message was received ?

To make sure that record has been sent you might need to subscribe a consumer on that topic.

@Artem Bilan i tried the following but the value got not updated
AtomicInteger messageReceived = new AtomicInteger(start);
if(listenerContainer!= null){
listenerContainer.setupMessageListener((MessageListener<String, String>) record -> {
messageReceived.incrementAndGet();});

The container has to be started to consume from topic.
